# Efficiency for a High Quantity of htaccess Redirects

Tags: performance, .htaccess, redirect, server

When setting up a list of links using a htaccess redirect for possible future affiliate link "beautification"  - would it be better to create a separate htaccess file within the sub folders that contains the specific links that get redirected?

The thinking here is: say there are 1000 links to be redirected - if these are placed in the the root folder htaccess file then - the server would have to scan through (1000 redirects) for every link clicked.

If 10 sub-folders each contain 100 of the 1000 redirects in each of their own htaccess file, would this be more efficient since there are less redirects to filter through by the server?

Of these 2 ideas - How does the Apache server handle this? Which would be more efficient way to do this?

I realize coding can be done for this also, but - as there may be dozens of different affiliate links from different companies with different coding methods.

Can someone please help me better understand? And no there are not 1000 redirects, just chose a nice round large number for the purpose of this question.

Thank You

Comment: Instead of a bazillion redirects why not have one with [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc)?

Comment: That's was my original option  -  read some more and some blogs stated this was faster - so I wanted to see the replies in a better forum (stackoverflow.com has been more useful than in solving/learning my issues - sometimes multiple constructive opinions can teach better than one)

Comment: Random blogs usually have no idea what they're talking about, or if they do then their advice is often dated. The way to find out *for sure* is to set things up today, on current software and hardware and benchmark it aggressively under as real-world conditions as you can simulate.

Comment: Can RewriteMap be done on a Shared Server - I have access to htaccess but not httpd.conf - please note: i am not a programmer - just a hobbyist - Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Each server has different restrictions. Try it and see.

Comment: Getting late... try tomorrow - Thank you for your help - if you know of a good website that best describe what is am trying to do  -  please post.

Comment: If placing a text map above the root folder - wouldn't I need access to place it there - Getting late... try tomorrow or am I placing the map in a folder within the root folder and just substitute its location, like it is in httpd.conf in the rewrite mod code?  - Thank you for your help - if you know of a good website that best describes what is am trying to do  -  please post.

Comment: The server will have access if the file permissions are correct.